# Closing popup div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can I get help correcting the code below? You can just copy and paste and try it yourself.  `Onmouseover` the popup div appears.  If I click <kbd>X</kbd> the popup div should close but it doesn't.  Only doubleclicking <kbd>X</kbd> closes the popup div.  `Onmouseover` it should always display a popup div though.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

</head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
display:block;
width:500px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid green;
}
.advert {
float:right;
overflow:hidden;
width:100px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid red;
}
.close {
float:right;
width:20px;
height:28px;
cursor:pointer;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container" onmouseover='getad(39);' onmouseout='hidead(39);changeback(39);'>
<div class='advert' id="39"  style="display:none;"><div class="close"><a href="javascript:closead(39)">X</a></div></div>
<input type="text" value="1" id="ad39" />
</div>


<div class="container" onmouseover='getad(40);' onmouseout='hidead(40);changeback(40);'>
<div class='advert' id="40" style="display:none;"><div class="close"><a href="javascript:closead(40)">X</a></div></div>
<input type="text" value="1" id="ad40" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getad(number) {
        
    if(document.getElementById('ad'+number).value==1) {
        if(document.getElementById(number).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(number).style.display = "block";
        
        }
    }
    
} 

function hidead(number) {
    
    if(document.getElementById('ad'+number).value==1) {
        if(document.getElementById(number).style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById(number).style.display = "none";
        
        }
    }
} 

function closead(number) {
    
    document.getElementById('ad'+number).value = 0;
    if(document.getElementById(number).style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById(number).style.display = "none";
        
        }

    
    
    }

    function changeback(number) {
    
    if(document.getElementById('ad'+number).value==0) {

    
    document.getElementById('ad'+number).value = 1;
    
    }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You IDs are wrong:

```
<div class='advert' id="39"  style="display:none;">
<div class='advert' id="40" style="display:none;">
```

should be:

```
<div class='advert' id="ad39"  style="display:none;">
<div class='advert' id="ad40" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in firefox and it works.

In IE8, it does not work.

This is the main reason why you should never write native Javascript...

Use JQuery or another JS framework.

First, it will make your code cross browser compatible.
Second, only 1 line of code will do what you need to do ;-)

Something like $(#39).hide() or $(#39).show()

Comment: I tested it in firefox and it doesn't work. I want the onmouseover of the container to display the ad.  So jquery wouldnt' make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that your ad isn't being removed. It's that in order to click the link that triggers the hidead() function, you must also be hovering the mouse cursor over the div that triggers getad() on mouseover.

So what is actually executing if you step through the actions is this.

Click event triggers on the  tag for the "X-link"
closead(number) fires and executes it's code.
Mouseout event fires and propagates to the parent 
hidead(number) fires and executes.
Mouseover event fires and propagates to the parent 
getad(number) fires and executes.

So your event is being unloaded, then immediately reloaded. Perhaps if you could provide some context, we could help you make this workable. I'm not sure under what circumstances you want to load an ad on mouseover, hide it on mouseout, and give the user a close button. That just seems like a lot of loading/unloading/flashing content that's going to annoy your visitor more than simply having a static ad that reloads every X seconds via AJAX or something.

Comment: i understand what your saying, is there anyway i can get my method to work?  What if disabling onmouseover and re-enabling onmouseover onmouseout?

Comment: I would actually start by moving away from native JS coding. This entire endeavor (and most JS code) can be simplified by using a framework library such as jQuery (http://jquery.com). From there you can easily bind/unbind events by using selectors and chain functions together. $('#ad39').val(0); $('#39').hide(); That would change your value as needed and hide the ad container. Far less code than you need to use to do it in native. And jQuery will handle cross-browser compatibility for you.